# Classic ASP How to update parent window with child window selection

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp-classic

I want to be able to update a parent window with a child window's selection. Let me put it this way, I have a field called Clients with a '+' button next to it. When someone clicks on the '+' button, I want it to open a new window with a table to search the entire dbo.clients.

Once the person has found the record they want, when they double click on it, I want the child window to close and the textbox in the parent window to update with the value chosen in the child one.

Can someone please give me a hand with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is more a JavaScript Problem than a asp Problem. try to use window.opener to address the parent window

Comment: Thanks for the info. I managed to get it working with the command you suggested. Thanks